# Floating title is not working in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of item with two iterations. I want a sticky title when the title scroll up from the view area. I have done it with jquery, but can't able to do in angular. Created a fiddle 
 https://jsfiddle.net/1vf5ska7/ 
I just to want to add a class in  tag when the title is goes up to the view area.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#l-content__desc__split1__body')).on('scroll', function() {


                });
```

**And the important thing is it is not a window scroll. It's a div scroll** 
Please help me. 
Thanks..

Comment: you want 'welcome' title to be fixed?

Comment: Provide the working jQuery demo. Should work the same. Did you put what you tried in a directive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a directive and operate on it. If `$window.pageYOffset` is greater than the position of the element you apply a specific class to that element which is positioned fixed.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 
app.directive('setClassOnTop', function ($window) {
    var $win = angular.element($window); // wrap window object as jQuery object    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                                    
            var title = angular.element(document.getElementById('sticky-title'));            
            var offsetTop = title[0].offsetTop;

            $win.on('scroll', function (e) {                
                if ($window.pageYOffset > offsetTop) {
                    angular.element(title[0]).addClass('floating-title');
                } else {
                    angular.element(title[0]).removeClass('floating-title');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And here is the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1vf5ska7/3/